# Verb Conjugations Database

Tags: database, nlp

Does anyone know of a good database for verb conjugations? I am building a natural language processing app. Although I've been able to make great use of WordNet it doesn't allow me to check the form of a verb in a conjugation database or conjugate other verbs.

I've thought about scraping a site like on of these:
    http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-find.html
    http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/find.html

and building my database from that. However I'd rather just download my own usable database. I'm not looking for a program or script to do this for me (not interested in NLTK)... I'd much rather a MySQL database (or something I can easily turn into a MySQL database) so I can do my own processing and computation.

Comment: If you take a list of irregular verbs in English (together with ther conjugated forms) it would be enough I believe. Anything that is not in the list will be a regular verb whose conjugatations can be coded regularly. So, are you asking for a resource that contains irregular English verbs?

Comment: Yes, a comprehensive list of irregular English verbs and their conjugations would work equally as well.

Comment: Did you ever get a database?

Comment: Since this question got closed, I opened the question on a different SE website: [Dataset of English verb forms](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/36017/2680)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a pretty good starting point, that is a table of irregular verbs with their conjugations which can be put into a MySQL database fairly easily:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs

Also see

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_irregular_verbs

Comment: I ended up using another online resource (that was easier for me to upload into MySQL) but thanks for the idea of just using an irregular verb db.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at GCIDE, which contains plurals, alt spellings and conjugations, and  is in XML format.

http://www.ibiblio.org/webster/

Comment: By the way, I'm curious. Which online resource did you end up using for this? I've been using GCIDE for a while but am open to other suggestions for obtaining verb conjugations and plural forms.

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure this (http://www.online-languages.info/english/irregular_verbs.php?l=1) was the one I used for irregular verb conjugations.

Comment: @wizardjoe  Where in the GCIDE are you finding conjugations?  When I look I only find definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [English Verb Conjugation and Inflectional Morphology](http://www.scientificpsychic.com/verbs1.html) as well.

Comment: While this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.