# Is there a database, API, or parsable text for getting verb conjugations?

Tags: nlp

This isn't directly a programming question, so I apologize in advance. I've been working on a grammar-free random sentence generator for a typing game I'd like to make, and I've been having a difficult time finding any parsable (or callable) data for getting verb conjugations. Ultimately, if I can't find anything like this, I'm going to have to go through the dictionary I've created and add first-person singular and plural, second-person singular and plural, third-person singular and plural, simple past, past participle, and present participle forms for every irregular verb.

This wouldn't be a problem in many languages, but there are so many irregular English verbs that this could take a long, long time to do manually. I'm not against the worse option, but I want to make sure I'm not going to be wasting obscene hours doing it myself when there is some database I can use instead.

I've seen http://www.scientificpsychic.com/verbs1.html and spoken with the creator, but he doesn't release his exact dictionary (just the classes for it). I've also seen sites like http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/find.html, which would be great for scraping, but that's a bit of a pain as well.

This question has been asked here before ( [Verb Conjugations Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424806/verb-conjugations-database) ), but the question was left unanswered, and the asker alluded to solving the problem but never said what the solution was.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MorphAdorner (Java) has a simple [Verb conjugator](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/conjugator/) (with online demo).

But if you are interested with an exhaustive listing you can check [Lexical Tools' Inflection Variants](https://lsg3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/current/docs/designDoc/UDF/flow/fi.html). After downloading [Lexical Tools](http://specialist.nlm.nih.gov/lvg/), you will be importing the data to your database server. Then you can just query the database using their library (Java).

[SimpleNLG](http://code.google.com/p/simplenlg/) also has this feature, and is very much related to Lexical Tool.

Comment: SimpleNLG has solved most of my problems. Thank you! I would have been in way over my head without it. Actually, I'm only using its lexicon XML file because I'm building my engine for use in Django, but I'll be using Scala for the game, so thumbs up.

Comment: Is there a conjugations API for Spanish->English? I.e., for an app I'm building, I need `quiero` recognized as the `I - present` form for `querer`