# English Word Declension and Conjugation

Tags: nlp

I am currently working on a Natural Language Parser and I need to be able to conjugate English Verbs and Nouns.

I already have a list of Verb Irregulars but I am struggling to find a set of "rules" if you will, for conjugating regular English verbs. I know there are a few, various rules such as: "if the word ends in 'X', then the plural form would end in 'Y'" with the most basic being add an s to the end.

I am looking for the rules for finding the: Base form, Past simple, Past participle, 3rd person singular, Present participle Gerund

Also, I would be looking to do the same for finding the plurals and possessive forms of any given noun, along with a list of regulars. I have had no source of results or luck in my searching in this area and any help with conjugating (for lack of a better word) nouns would be very helpful.

[edit]
A link to a list of irregular nouns and a list of rules like: if the word ends in a consonant, then ad "s" (or whatever) would be awesome!!!
[/edit]

One more thing... for my english ver irregulars, I am using [this site](http://www.online-languages.info/english/irregular_verbs.php?l=1)

Sorry for what appears to be the lack of searching, trust me I have looked.

Comment: Have you looked at Wordnet?  http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Comment: what about english.stackexhange.com

Comment: Yes I am using wordnet, it really only gives me the singular form of each word.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538425/is-there-a-database-api-or-parsable-text-for-getting-verb-conjugations/9543779#9543779

Answer (score 4):

after a few days I think I figured out a solution for making all english words plural or past tense etc...

For both the verbs and the nouns there were a set of irregular words that were relatively easy to find, as well as a set of rules for each. The main problem I was having was that very often their were rules such as

if ending is X then drop the last letter and add 'Y'
but sometimes if ending is X, don't drop the last letter and add 'Z'

Obvious this is very hit or miss for defining rules for the language.

But my solution was, I would look at both of those forms that could be possible, then look at the google n gram data and compare. Whichever one was more frequent, became the plural form of the word.