# English word database with plurals/conjugations

Tags: mysql, database, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Verb Conjugations Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424806/verb-conjugations-database)

I'm looking for an English word database in MySQL, or easily convertible to MySQL, that contains verb conjugations and plural/singular forms. I've looked at a couple of options: WordNet, GCIDE, etc.

However GCIDE does not seem to be comprehensive and WordNet does not seem to label conjugations by tense (correct me if I'm wrong).

My problem is similar to this one:
[Verb Conjugations Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424806/verb-conjugations-database/10192400)

But it seems like no satisfactory, free solution was shared.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is a morphological analyzer. Try [WebJspell](http://natura.di.uminho.pt/webjspell/jsol.pl?ling=en) to check if JSpell would help you.

You can use the Jspell from Perl using the [Lingua::Jspell](http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Lingua-Jspell-1.84/lib/Lingua/Jspell.pm). Its documentation includes lots of examples.

If you really need a list of words to add to your database you can extract it from JSpell dictionary. Take a look at the [foreach_word](http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Lingua-Jspell-1.84/lib/Lingua/Jspell/DictManager.pm#foreach_word) method. The example code bellow should guide you, but I could not try it so I am not sure it will work.

```
$dic = jspell::dict::init("../en/en.dic") or die "could not open en.dic";
$en_dict = jspell::new("en") or die "could not load en

$dic->foreach_word(
    sub {
        # gets each word from dictionary

        my @der = $en_dict->der($word);

        foreach $dword (@der) {
            # gets the features
        my @fea = $pt_dict->fea($dword);
            # do something with the $dword and the array of features @fea
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like WebJspell doesn't seem to inflect irregular verbs (try "run" or "arise") or pluralize irregular nouns (try "analysis") properly. The list of irregular verbs is manageable so that I can build out a db by hand, but irregular nouns are a problem.

Comment: Indeed. I already successfully used it for Portuguese, but not for English. Maybe you should investigate other morphological analyzer, like Hunspell. It includes a very nice French dictionary with morphologic information, but I don't know if the English dictionary also includes it.